# gdb throwing error saying program to have a function "malloc"

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I executed following commands in gdb and console output is as follows:

```
Rohan_gdb$ set $var = 15
Rohan_gdb$ p $var
$5 = 0xf
Rohan_gdb$ set $var = (int *)10
Rohan_gdb$ p $var
$6 = (int *) 0xa
Rohan_gdb$ set $char = "abc"
Rohan_gdb$ p $char
$7 = "abc"
Rohan_gdb$ set $char = (char *)"xyz"
evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc".
```

(here I got error)

```
Rohan_gdb$ p $char
$8 = "abc"
Rohan_gdb$
```

Here I am debugging with target and not native debugging. I am using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2 version. Is it possible to solve using scripts.

Comment: Can you give some more details about your target system - is it an embedded / bare metal system, or a process running under an OS. Do you use `malloc` in the code, if not, try adding a call to `malloc` and see if you get a linkage error. If it doesn't work, you have to consider - will you be requiring `malloc` in your system down the line, or do you just need to work around the gdb issue? What implementation of the C standard library are you using, if at all? `stdio` generally requires `malloc`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to solve your specific problem, but I ran across something similar.  Given the age of the question, maybe this'll provide a clue.

The problem is that your script is trying to store away a value in a buffer and it must allocated a new buffer for that storage.   The storage requirement is likely the result of the cast or because that second string is not in the constant strings within your binary.

To fix, either change your code to not require a malloc (which is a bit of hit or miss, as far as I can tell).   Or make the malloc symbol available;  load a symbol table that allows gdb to resolve the "_malloc" symbol.

Comment: malloc is in the standard C library, how do you load a symbol for that?

Comment: That's a really good question.   Normally, the symbols for the standard C library are sort of "just there" for the environments I work in.  Given the context of OP's question, I suspect they are in an environment where this isn't the case.  Frankly, the easiest solution would be to compile a stub wrapper around malloc(), link against it and manually call that.   Honestly, it has been so long since I've had to build the standard lib, I wouldn't know how to do it these days without a bunch of research.

Answer (score 0):

All values are interpreted in the current language. This means, for example, that if the current source language is C/C++ then searching for the string “hello” includes the trailing `\0`. The null terminator can be removed from searching by using casts, e.g.: `{char[5]}"hello"`.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Searching-Memory.html

Example:
https://github.com/PhoenixInteractiveNL/emuDownloadCenter/wiki/Emulator-wincpc <-> WinCPC is **the Borland Delphi port** of an Amstrad CPC emulator called vbCPC.

```
F:\flynns_WinCPC>gdb wincpc.exe<br>
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6<br>
...<br>
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".<br>
...<br>
Reading symbols from F:\flynns_WinCPC\wincpc.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.<br>
(gdb) info files<br>
Symbols from "F:\flynns_WinCPC\wincpc.exe".<br>
Local exec file:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  `F:\flynns_WinCPC\wincpc.exe', file type pei-i386.<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        Entry point: 0x558448<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x00401000 - 0x005587ec is CODE<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x00559000 - 0x0055f7f8 is DATA<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x007bf000 - 0x007c1b88 is .idata<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x007c3000 - 0x007c301f is .rdata<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x007c4000 - 0x007db530 is .reloc<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;        0x007dc000 - 0x00861c00 is .rsrc<br>
(gdb) find 0x00401000,0x00861c00,'m','e','m','o','r','y'<br>
0x48b224<br>
0x48b2e8<br>
0x48b312<br>
0x48b33a<br>
0x48b354<br>
0x48c2cc<br>
0x48cfcb<br>
0x82d910<br>
0x841484<br>
0x8456f9<br>
10 patterns found.<br>
(gdb) find 0x00401000,0x00861c00, <strong>{char[6]}</strong> "memory"<br>
evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc".<br>
```